# Как сделать обратную сортировку пунктов?

Tags: javascript, list, список

Имеется большое количество пунктов по такой структуре:

- Ноутбуки
  -- Acer
  -- Samsung
  -- Lenovo
- Планшеты
  -- Acer
  -- Samsung
  -- Lenovo
- Телевизоры
  -- Acer
  -- Samsung
  -- Lenovo

Как можно в модуле вывода категорий вывести с помощью JS категории так, чтобы вид был подобный:

- Samsung:
  -- Телевизоры
  -- Ноутбуки
   -- Планшеты
- Acer
  --Телевизоры
   --Ноутбуки
   --Планшеты
- Lenovo
   -- Телевизоры
   -- Ноутбуки
   --Планшеты

```html
<ul>
  <li class="heading"><a>Ноутбуки</a></li>
  <li>      
     <ul>
       <li><a>Acer</a></li>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="heading"><a>Ноутбуки</a></li>
  <li>      
     <ul>
       <li><a>Acer</a></li>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li class="heading"><a>Планшеты</a></li>
  <li>      
     <ul>
       <li><a>Acer</a></li>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: метка javascript, вывести через PHP, предоставлена только html. Вы точно 3 года на Stackoverflow?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский прошу прощения, поправил. Глупая помарка

Comment: У вас элементы `<ul>` вложены непосредственно в элементы `<ul>` — это невалидная разметка. Нужно вложенные `<ul>` обернуть в `<li>`...

Comment: @wololo исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, пройтись по исходному списку, сформировав из него `Map`. В качестве ключа использовать название компании, а в качестве значения массив разновидностей техники, производимой компанией.

Затем пройтись по `Map`, формируя результирующий список. Ключи `Map` (названия компаний) использовать в качестве элементов списка, а из значений `Map` (массивов разновидностей техники) формировать вложенные списки.

```js
let heading = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
let map = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < heading.length; ++i) {
    let a = heading[i].querySelectorAll("a");
    let groupName = a[0].textContent.trim();
    for (let j = 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
        let companyName = a[j].textContent.trim();
        let companyGroups = map.get(companyName);
        if (companyGroups)
            companyGroups.push(groupName);
        else
            map.set(companyName, [groupName]);
    }
}

let compare = (new Intl.Collator("ru")).compare;
let ul = document.createElement("ul");
ul.className = "some-style";
let companies = Array.from(map.keys()).sort(compare);
for (let companyName of companies) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.textContent = companyName;
    li.append(a);
    
    let li_ul = document.createElement("ul");
    let companyGroups = map.get(companyName).sort(compare);
    for (let groupName of companyGroups) {
        let li = document.createElement("li");
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.textContent = groupName;
        li.append(a);
        li_ul.append(li);
    }
    li.append(li_ul);
    
    ul.append(li);
}

document.body.append(ul);
```

```css
.some-style {
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="heading"><a>Телевизоры</a>   
     <ul>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="heading"><a>Планшеты</a>   
     <ul>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Acer</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  <li class="heading"><a>Ноутбуки</a>     
     <ul>
       <li><a>Lenovo</a></li>
       <li><a>Samsung</a></li>
       <li><a>Acer</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как вставить конструкцию в определенный существующий элемент на странице, а не в `body` с сохранением `href=""` в ссылках?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, также как и в `body`, просто вызовете метод [`append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) у этого элемента. Например, если среди всех `div` на странице есть единственный с классом `my-div`, то можно так: `document.querySelector(".my-div").append(ul);`. `append` добавляет в конец элемента. В начало можно добавить с помощью [`prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend).

Comment: Благодарю, немного не так использовал querySelector. Подскажите, а почему могут удаляться href ещё?

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, пока не очень понятно, как вы работаете с атрибутом `href`. Если в коде формирования списка вы допишите что-то вроде `a.href = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/";`, то это должно работать.